# how to avoid the changing ip in LAN?

Tags: networking, ip, local-area-network

In my LAN it has 10 systems and one commom server. Before start a server, if any other systems start(on) means, the server ip will assign to that particular system in automatically. Here how to prevent to changing IP?

Answer (score 3):

you need to set up static ip's for each system, follow the guides here
http://portforward.com/networking/staticip.htm

Comment: You just need to set a static IP for the server, not the entire network. He could also setup a DHCP reservation for the server by MAC address so that each time the server requests an IP it gets the same and no other host in the DHCP pool gets the server's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. Configure your DHCP server to assign a specific IP address based on the MAC address (how you do this depends on the DHCP server you use)
2. Configure your DHCP server to limit the IP addresses it assigns to a specific range (the specifics depend on the DHCP server), then configure any computers you want to have unchanging ips to have a static ip in that range (the specifics depend on the OS they use).